# IIS auth failure with Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-authentication

I have an application that has been running under IIS on a Server 2012 server for years. Recently, authentication seems to have stopped working and I have no idea why.

The site is setup to use Windows authentication and I am accessing it with the same PowerShell code I have always used. Normally, this code:

```
$RequestUrl = 'https://app.site.com/dir'
$DomainCredential = Get-Credential
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RequestUrl -Credential $DomainCredential
```

Should result in this in the IIS log:

> #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

> 2020-07-07 16:48:58  GET  stem>  443 -  Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.18362.752 - 401 2 5 0

> 2020-07-07 16:48:59  GET   443   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.18362.752 - 200 0 0 999

Now, however (again, without any code changes), the IIS log shows:

> #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

> 2020-07-08 19:33:23  GET   443 -  Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.18362.752 - 401 2 5 0

> 2020-07-08 19:33:28  GET   443 -  Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.18362.752 - 401 1 3221225581 5046

and the response is "401 Unathorized". It appears that PowerShell is not passing the credential.

I verified that I am getting back a WWW-Authenticate header. I rebooted the server, just-in-case, but it did not help. I also enabled directory browsing for a moment and was able to authenticate in my browser and see the files. Finally, I worked with the developer of the app and he confirmed that my request is not getting through, I am getting stuck at IIS.

What gives?

Comment: First things first - If you open your web browser using the **same** credential set as with your script, does it work?

Comment: If I enable directory browsing, then I can view the files. I am connecting to a REST API, so I can't really do much in the browser.

Comment: Turns out that it appears to be a network issue. The server hosting the app does not get a response on the VIP of the back-end servers (the API pulls data from another application). When I update the hosts file to point to one of the servers, I stop being hit with 401.

Comment: Directly access the URL in the browser will construct an HTTP Get request. This is a good step to pinpoint the issue. Please share the solution with us and mark it as an answer.